# Display Tag Excerpt Tooltips in Suggested Edits

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

On many pages, hovering over the tag produces a Tag Wiki Excerpt tooltip:

[image]

Can we make these work for the [Suggested Edits review page?](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits)  I know it's a small thing, but it would make reviewing and approving edits a bit easier, especially for tag edits.