# There are no tag bubbles when editing questions

Tags: bug, edits, tag-bubble

When editing a question, hovering over the question's tags does not pop up the tag bubble.

As edits can involve re-tagging, being able to see the excerpt in the tag bubble would be really useful as a reminder of the exact tag usage.

It would make it easier to accurately determine if the tag is viable for that particular question or not.
(I cannot remember them all, although maybe that's just because I'm getting old..).

---

I'm going to assume this is not by-design as I cannot think of a reason for not having this functionality.
And I'm going with "bug" not "feature-request" because I am guessing this *should* already happen.

Comment: Do you mean the black popup? Those have never appeared when editing tags, because when you start typing it suggests up to six tags below. If you want to see the tag excerpt, you can just click on the tag to convert it to text, and the tag suggestion box will pop up below the input box.

Comment: "*you can just click on the tag to convert it to text, and the tag suggestion box will pop up below the input box*" that's not really a good system though, it's a bit of a workaround. Although, I did not know about that so thanks for the info