# Provide tag description when performing tag edits

Tags: feature-request, tags

I do a lot of tag editing on both [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com) and the [Cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com) site. When I'm looking at tags when reading questions all the tags have tag descriptions. The tag description also pops up when a new tag is proposed by the system. However, when I am adding / removing tags during "*tag edits*" then the tag description *of existing tags* does **not** pop up. Obviously it is handy to look at existing tags descriptions to check if the flags are correct.

Is there any way to enable tag descriptions when performing tag edits? I guess this is related to [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168035/176060) but I'm not sure if that covers tag-edits specifically.

Comment: I looked at the first 20 (!) questions I found about this, and then one pops up with **status-deferred** from 2013 when editing the question for the third time. In SE terms this means that you can stick it somewhere the sun doesn't shine. Guys, SE needs to use some kind of way of prioritizing and sorting feature requests. This one should be relatively simple to implement...

Comment: It might be simple, or it might not be. It probably is somewhere on the (back)log, seeing that it has a status* tag. Probably it is somewhere at the bottom, or on a list of things that don't require immediate attention. Seeing that Dev time is limited don't get your hopes up.

Comment: Yeah, maybe having a hoover over an input field is not that easy. Maybe I can check if I can trigger it myself. **It probably is somewhere on the (back)log** is of course fine from a company perspective, **but as input to the user base it is no good whatsover.** What the heck are we supposed to expect from that? People will just stop voting: the question cannot be found in any meaningful way, and if they vote they will just be disappointed.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes don't get wound up too much :) SE's well-known for being slow with feature requests (and by slow I mean about a once-in-a-decade slow). They are much more interested in making stuff like Collectives or Teams for paying customers than for mere mortals that provide content for them to sell. We are *finally* getting some updates to the review queue experience, but that's about it for now - I will be happy to be proven wrong.

Comment: The description doesn't get shown if you hover, but _does_ if you click on it - that puts the tag into editing mode and the autocomplete shows the tag in question and other similar tags.

Comment: OK, that's actually a reasonable workaround, I didn't notice that before. May also show that it would be relatively easy to fix maybe (click vs hoover).